# Quirky __set() magic function

Tags: php

Can anyone please explain me a logic in this behaviour?

Consider the following situation:

```
class EPPDomain
{
    protected $myField;

    public static function buildEPPDomain($fieldValue)
    {
        $me = new self();
        $me->myField = $fieldValue;
        return $me;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->$name = "prefix_".value;
    }
}

class EPPDomainFactory
{
    public static function buildEPPDomain($fieldValue)
    {
        $me = new EPPDomain();
        $me->myField = $fieldValue;
        return $me;
    }
}
```

So

```
$dmn = EPPDomain::buildEPPDomain("myValue");
echo $dmn->myField;
```

Expected

```
prefix_myValue
```

Actual

```
myValue
```

Obviously,

```
$dmn = EPPDomainFactory::buildEPPDomain("myValue");
echo $dmn->myField;
```

Works as expected outputting

```
prefix_myValue
```

According to __set description on http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

> __set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.

When I create an instance of EPPDomain in a static method of EPPDomain class all protected properties are supposed to be inaccessible. Therefore __set should be called but it is not

I know it also says

> Property overloading only works in object context. These magic methods
>   will not be triggered in static context. Therefore these methods
>   should not be declared static. As of PHP 5.3.0, a warning is issued if
>   one of the magic overloading methods is declared static.

But I have an inpression that it just states that __set method should be a class member function and should not be static. That is it and it seems it has nothing to do with the situation I am facing.

Is that a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: It would be very beneficial if you could *simplify* that example code. It's too convoluted to demonstrate your point.

Comment: Done, sorry, my code is much more complicated and I was trying to simplify it as much as possible. Probably did not try hard enough. This version should look better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `protected` property is *accessible* to all code in the same or inheriting *classes*. The emphasis being on *class*.

```
class Foo {

    protected $bar;

    public function foo() {
        $foo = new self;
        $foo->bar = 'baz';
    }

}
```

This works just fine. The *class* is working on an *instance* of itself, it has access to its own properties. It's not about "foreign instances", it's about the class.

The point of protected properties is that their presence or implementation should only be relevant to the class that defines them. Other code shouldn't mess with them directly. Since one can assume that a class knows how to deal with its own properties, a class is trusted to manipulate properties of any object of its type.

Comment: Nice, I was not aware that private/protected properties would be still accessible even if the object was created in a static factory method that belongs to the same class. Effectively this forces developers to have factory methods in different classes. Thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior, because a method does have access to protected (and even private) properties of instances of its class.