# why uninitialized property is made public in class?

Tags: php, oop

Consider below code please:

```
class foo {
    function bar() {
        $this->baz = 'hello there!';
    }
}

$f = new foo;
$f->bar();
echo $f->baz; // hello there!
```

Why does above code work ? I mean I have not initialized the `$baz` variable and also I am not using `__get` and `__set` magic methods. I was expecting it would give me error, but it seems the `$baz` has been created and assigned `public` visibility. (BTW it does give error in static context though)

Comment: __get & __set magic methods are called only if a property is accessed from outside the visibility scope. As you are assigning baz in the class itself, they are not called. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126801/quirky-set-magic-function

Comment: Because the designers of PHP chose for it to create new properties if your assigned to non-existent properties; in the same way that assigning a value creates a new local variable if it doesn't already exist... and making it anything other than public by default would be less useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who told that you are not initialized,You have initialized by the statement `$this->baz = 'hello there!';`
This is how object oriented concept works.You are declaring a class , creating an instance for that class and then accessing that function and at last echoing a variable in that member function,This is how object orientation works...

Answer (score 2):

It's because how PHP works. If you set uninitialized property, it will be created even without `__set`. On the other hand, if you try to read uninitialized property, you end with warning.

Answer (score 1):

By default it is set to public.

Refer to this link:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php