# Undefined class property still not giving any error

Tags: php, oop

I am running below code, still its not throwing an error or warning, name property is not defined in the User class, I am using PHP 5.5.15

```
<?php
class user{

}

$obj = new user;
$obj->name = 'John';
echo $obj->name;

?>
```

Comment: @Swellar read a question please: "still its not throwing an error or warning".

Comment: @Swellar I think it is. Maybe OP doesn't have any `error_reporting` enabled.

Comment: Similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711459/why-uninitialized-property-is-made-public-in-class/22711647

Comment: @u_mulder error_reporting is enabled, however i got answer from your link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711459/why-uninitialized-property-is-made-public-in-class/22711647
It's because how PHP works. If you set uninitialized property, it will be created even without __set. On the other hand, if you try to read uninitialized property, you end with warning.

Comment: Thank you, I can read answers to questions which I close as dupes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the newly created class with something inside and create a variable.

```
class user {

  public $name;

  function __construct() {
      $this->name = 'John';
  }

  public function show() {
      echo $this->name;
  }

}

$obj = new user();
$obj->show();
```